# How can I assign a function to a button in google script

Tags: javascript

I created a prompt in google script, with two buttons. If clicked OK, I want a function to run, if not, a dialog says "The user clicked no". The buttons are generated correctly, and the function works. I know this, 'cause I know how to assign it to an item menu.

> makefile is the function I'm trying to run

```
function AFIP() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    var response =   ui.alert('Title', 'Yo want to generare the file?',
                     ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

    if (response == ui.Button.OK) {
        makefile;
    } else {
        Logger.log('The user clicked "No" or the close button in the dialog\'s title  bar.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this for the definition of the makefile function:

```
function makefile() {
  Logger.log("makefile() has been executed.");
}
```

Your code works, with one change. Instead of:

```
makefile;
```

It should be:

```
makefile();
```